# Reloading Eclipse view

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plugin with a view that creates a tableviewer based on different files found in the selected project (the workspace has more than one project loaded). My problem is that when I try to reload the view the information remains the same as on the first run after Eclipse started.

What should I do in order to reload the content provider everytime I reload the view ?

Comment: Show us how you are reloading the view

Comment: Window->Show View->View Name , I mean this reloading not the one with viewer.setInput(contentProvider)

Answer (score 1):

To be told about which part is active you need to use `IPartListener2`. Make your ViewPart implement `IPartListener2`.

Set up the listener in the `createPartControl`:

```
@Override
public void createPartControl(final Composite parent)
{
  ....

  getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(this);
}
```

Remove the listener in `dispose`:

```
@Override
public void dispose()
{
  super.dispose();

  ...

  getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().removePartListener(this);
}
```

You will have to implement the various methods of `IPartListener`, most of these don't need to do anything, the `partVisible` method is called when your view (or any other part) is shown:

```
@Override
public void partVisible(final IWorkbenchPartReference ref)
{
  if (ref.getId().equals("your view id"))
   {
     // Your view has become visible ... add code here to update the table
   }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, it seems that once the view is loaded from window option it uses only the project that was selected at that time.....

Comment: You will have to find out what the new selection is in the partVisible

Comment: What do you mean ? :)

Comment: I mean that each time your part becomes active you must ask Eclipse what the current selection is and rebuild your table's contents.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my partVisible looks:

```
public void partVisible(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (partRef.getId().equals("view id taken from extensions"))
       {

        getWorkspacePath();
        viewer.remove(TableContent.INSTANCE.getRow());
        viewer.setInput(TableContent.INSTANCE.updateContentProvider());
        viewer.refresh();

       }
}
```

The path is updated (i've displayed the path in the view) but the content of the table isn't....updateContentProvider contains the call of the functions that need to parse some files in the selected project....

Comment: Have you checked if the CableContent.INSTANCE.updateContentProvider() function does the update correctly?